# XPath Text or Child Node

Tags: html, xpath, contains

I have a Div element on a page which is used to display error messages. This div is invisible unless it is populated.

Unfortunately, the content type is inconsistent. In some cases it can have a direct child text node, which I could pick up with:

> contains(text(),'*'))

or it can contain a `<span>` which contains its own child text node, which I could pick up with:

> //div/span[contains(text(),'*')]

As much as I would like to, I cannot change this behaviour.

***Example 1***:

```
<div id="TopErrorMessageDiv">Error Message</div>
```

***Example 2***:

```
<div id="TopErrorMessageDiv">
    <span style="something">Error Message 1<br>Error Message 2</span>
</div>
```

Fortunately, I really don't need to know the contents, I just need to know if the div is non-empty.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You could try [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/boolean) xpath function. If node exist it returns true e.g. `boolean(//div[@id="TopErrorMessageDiv"]//text())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
//div[@id="TopErrorMessageDiv" and .//text()]
```

to match `div` that contains any text content

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you as well

```
//div[@id="TopErrorMessageDiv" and string-length(text()) > 0]
```